# Jenkins AWS ECR Login Failing

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins

I am trying to setup `Jenkins` pipeline and as the first step I am trying to build, tag and push the `Docker` image to `AWS ECR`. The first thing that I do in the pipeline is running the following command which will log me in into `AWS`, however it fails - `/usr/local/bin/aws ecr get-login-password --region us-west-2 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin 865995624483.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/superhero-match/superhero-suggestions`.

This is the output that I get:

```
Started by GitHub push by superhero-match
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/superhero-suggestions
No credentials specified
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/superhero-match/superhero-suggestions.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/superhero-match/superhero-suggestions.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git fetch --tags --progress -- https://github.com/superhero-match/superhero-suggestions.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 35bbac997033e99e5ba0dddbe91c238058f196db (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 35bbac997033e99e5ba0dddbe91c238058f196db # timeout=10
Commit message: "Update README file"
 > git rev-list --no-walk d03cc8f5f051018338493b844606710ba982da3c # timeout=10
[superhero-suggestions] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins7240644465665447873.sh
+ docker login --username AWS --password-stdin 865995624483.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/superhero-match/superhero-suggestions
+ /usr/local/bin/aws ecr get-login-password --region us-west-2
Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".
Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

But when I run exactly the same command from terminal it works perfectly fine.

I am using the `AWS-CLI v2`.

Comment: Jenkins executes commands under `jenkins` user. When you run command yourself, `aws` cli will use your credentials. `jenkins` user seems not to have aws profile created.

Comment: @Marcin How do I create aws profile for `jenkins` user?

Comment: @Marcin I configured global environment variables for access key, secret key and default region and it works now. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear. If you don't mind I will make answer then.

Comment: You should consider using: https://plugins.jenkins.io/aws-credentials/

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, the reason is that Jenkins typically executes its builds under `jenkins` user. Whereas when OP  tried manually in the CLI, the user is different.

It worked from CLI because the OP's user has aws credentials correctly set. This is not the case for `jenkins` user.